# How do I make a dictionary of events?

Tags: c#, events

I want to have a dictionary of events, so far I have

```
private Dictionary<T, event Action> dictionaryOfEvents;
```

is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: dictionary of events and what?

Comment: Would that be the methods or calls to them you want to store?

Comment: Please explain why you think you need a collection of events. That will allow us to help you solve your problem instead of answering a technicality.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd he probably wants to unsubscribe from the events. I would use a list of delegates for that. Don't know why he needs a dictionary.

Comment: @rezomegreldize - In that case it might be better to implement IDisposable on all types and unregister in the dispose method. the collection could then simply be a `IList<IDisposable>` But that is just guessing and currently not an answer to the question.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd T is an enum type so I want to be able to call a set of functions for each value in an enum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't have dictionary of events, though you can have dictionary of delegates.

```
private Dictionary<int, YourDelegate> delegates = new Dictionary<int, YourDelegate>();
```

where `YourDelegate` can be any delegate type.

Comment: I will do that but I will use a List<YourDelegate> as the value part of the dictionary so that I can have multiple YourDelegates per key.

Comment: @IanHern No need to use `List<YourDelegate>` just `YourDelegate` is enough [delegates can be combined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173175.aspx)

Comment: While it is true that delegates can be combined/added, once they are they get called together; this may be just what one wants but maybe it isn't. If accessing them freely is desired then maybe a List or even a second, inner Dictionary could the right solution.

Answer (score 5):

Event is not a type but Action is. So for instance you can write:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // declaration
  Dictionary<string, Action> dictionaryOfEvents = new Dictionary<string, Action>();

   // test data
  dictionaryOfEvents.Add("Test1", delegate() { testMe1(); });
  dictionaryOfEvents.Add("Test2", delegate() { testMe2(); });
  dictionaryOfEvents.Add("Test3", delegate() { button2_Click(button2, null); });

  // usage 1
  foreach(string a in dictionaryOfEvents.Keys )
    {  Console.Write("Calling "  + a  +  ":"); dictionaryOfEvents[a]();}

  // usage 2
  foreach(Action a in dictionaryOfEvents.Values) a();

  // usage 3
  dictionaryOfEvents["test2"]();

}

void testMe1() { Console.WriteLine("One for the Money"); }        
void testMe2() { Console.WriteLine("One More for the Road"); }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly define a dictionary of event types but you can define the event inside a class instead.

```
private Dictionary<string, MyEventManager> dictionaryOfEvents;

dictionaryOfEvents["key1"].CallMyEvent();
```

Example implementation of MyEventManager Class :

```
public class MyEventManager {

   public event Action MyEvent;
   public void CallMyEvent => MyEvent.Invoke()
}
```